# Liquibase Rollback in Teamcity pipelines

Tags: microservices, teamcity, liquibase, cicd, rollback

I'm trying to automate liquibase rollback in teamcity pipeline. I have configured liquibase in all services using maven. For each service I have liquibase:update DB pipeline and they are working fine.

Now how can I implement automatic rollback in teamcity and which of the following (count , tag or date) should I make use of?

I have tried tag rollback.

Tag : Tagging dbchangelog table with current MS version that is getting deployed and then doing database deployment with liquibase:update. This way I can rollback any version by giving rollbackTag=version. But the problem is when I rollback last 2 tags(0.0.1,0.0.2) and then deploy the latest MS version(0.0.3), the all changes gets tagged under 0.0.3!! So In future, If I want to rollback for 0.0.3, all changes for 0.0.1, 0.0.2, 0.0.3 will be gone!!

Answer (score 1):

Liquibase changes always have only one tag. So, if there aren't new deployments since the last time you tagged, Liquibase will override the last tag with your new one.

A few options for working around this issue:

Use two tags, `PREVIOUS` and `LATEST`. Then before doing an update, tag with `PREVIOUS`. Then after the update, tag with `LATEST`.

Use [rollback-one-update](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/rollback/rollback-one-update.html) which is a pro feature.

Or [rollback-to-date](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/rollback/rollback-to-date.html) and track the timestamp for each version. You could do that in a separate database table, or in a file. You can use whatever approach makes the most sense.